# VOIP XCode 8, Swift 3 and iOS 9.x

Tags: ios, swift, voip, callkit

I want to run VOIP push on both iOS 9 and iOS 10 from xcode 8. But on registering VOIP push it crashes on iOS 9.x. But it runs smoothly on iOS 10.
`let pushRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: DispatchQueue.main)
pushRegistry.delegate = self
pushRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushType.voIP]`

it crashes on 3rd line.

Note :- I have also integrated  call kit. But I have iOS 10 check implemented all through the code.

I also did the same in speaker box (default iOS project for VOIP and call kit) but the same problem occurs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What exact version/build of Xcode 8 are you using to build your app? There was a known issue, fixed in the final version of Xcode 8.1, which could cause Swift apps which use new iOS 10-only frameworks (including CallKit) to crash on older versions of iOS (9 and earlier).

I recommend that you ensure you are using the latest version of Xcode available and recompile your app.

Comment: Thanks. Problem Solved.

Comment: Great! Please kindly mark the question as 'Answered'